# Need assistance: proof of differentiability & directional derivate of $x^2\cdot y\cdot (x^2+y^2)^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I really need some help/guidance with the following tasks:

Given is the function $x^2\cdot y\cdot (x^2+y^2)^{-1}$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ with $f(0,0)=0$.

1) Is this function partial differentiable?

- I simply would say: YES, because $f$ is a composition of two differentiable functions (except for $(0,0)$).
- However, I'm sure I have to show something; I just don't know what/how.

2) Is this function continuously differentiable?

- The function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\}$
- The function is also continuous in $(0,0)$ since: $\lim \limits_{x\to0, y=0} \frac{x^20}{x^2} = 0\lim \limits_{y\to 0, x=0} \frac{0y}{y^2} = 0\lim \limits_{x\to 0, y=x} \frac{x^3}{2x^2} = 0$.
- I could also take two sequences converging to $0$ and put them in: $\dfrac{\frac{1}{n^2} \cdot \frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^2}} = \frac{1}{2n} \to 0$.
- Is this enough for the proof of continuity?
- If the function is partial differentiable, then it is also cointinuously differentiable- right?

3) Is this function (totally) differentiable?

4) Calculate the directional derivate of the function in direction $d=(\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha)$